# File object transferred using Socket.IO becomes 'ArrayBuffer'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, socket.io

When I transfer a file object (`File` [interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/File)) using Socket.IO with Typescript, the file becomes an `ArrayBuffer` on the receiving end.

Is there any way to transform the `ArrayBuffer` back into a `File`, or should I not send the entire file object using socket io (send name, data, mime type separately)?

Comment: File is just a special Blob, ArrayBuffer to Blob is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `ArrayBuffer` to `Blob` or `File` constructor

```
const file = new Blob([ab])
```

```
const file = new File([ab], "filename.ext", {type:/* valid MIME type */})
```

Comment: I tried that, `var file : File = new Blob(arraybuffer);` however, I get the error that the `Blob` class is missing the `lastModifiedDate` that the `File` requires, and so cannot be converted. If I force it using typecasting, I get the error: `core.es5.js:1084 ERROR TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': Iterator getter is not callable.`

Comment: Missed the update, will try the second line, thanks!

Comment: If `lastModifiedDate` is required by your application you can set that property at the object at the third parameter of `File()` constructor